# Architecture for service continuity

Tags: service, architecture

Could you recommend some literature on software architecture patterns for assembling services that offer a high degree of "continuity" when dealing with software updates/releases.

For instance, in an enterprise where several applications are interconnected, and dependent on their resources, of course, like databases, how to achieve zero downtime when performing an update/release? Typical scenarios include changing DB design, and several service contracts at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Statelessness is probably the single most important factor in building a service layer that can be upgraded with zero downtime.  This allows you to spin up new versions of the software, do a load-balancer switch, and shut down the old versions.

This can be achieved with stateful systems, but you have to be able to monitor them for existing connections, and control your load balancer much more carefully while you wait for the existing sessions to expire.

Database design changes are much more complicated, and generally just involve planning so that the changes are always backwards compatible.  You need to ensure that your database will allow running both the old and new versions of the service simultaneously.

That doesn't mean you can't make a breaking change, it just means that you generally need to make it in two steps.  For example, renaming a field becomes:

1. Add new column
2. Deploy new version of service that reads from old column when data is not present in the new column, but only writes to new column
3. Move data to new column
4. Deploy new service that only reads/writes new column
5. Delete old column

This is a giant pain, but for some systems you really do need this kind of uptime requirements.  I've also had to do this when it takes a long time (sometimes weeks) to move the data to the new location.

Finally, and this part is really important.  Make sure your services are autonomous.  Do not have several services reading/writing to the same table.  It's a giant mess, and migrating multiple services simultaneously is a nightmare.